# Split a dataframe into a list of dataframes, but how to re-merge?

Tags: r, split

I have a big ol' data frame with two ID columns for courses and users, and I needed to split it into one dataframe per course to do some further analysis/subsetting. After eliminating quite a few rows from each of the individual course dataframes, I'll need to stick them back together.

I split it up using, you guessed it, `split`, and that worked exactly as I needed it to. However, unsplitting was harder than I thought. The R documentation says that "`unsplit` reverses the effect of `split`," but my reading on the web so far is suggesting that that is not the case when the elements of the split-out list are themselves dataframes.

What can I do to rejoin my modified dfs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a place for `do.call`. Simply calling `df <- rbind(split.df)` will result in a weird and useless list object, but `do.call("rbind", split.df)` should give you the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

`unsplit()` will work / does seem to work in the general situation that you describe, but not the particular situation of removing rows from the thus split data frame.

Consider

```
> spl <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
> str(spl, max = 1)
List of 3
 $ 4:'data.frame':  11 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ 6:'data.frame':  7 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ 8:'data.frame':  14 obs. of  11 variables:
> str(unsplit(spl, f = mtcars$cyl))
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

As we can see, `unsplit()` can undo a split. However, in the case where the split data frame is further worked upon and altered to remove rows, there will be a mismatch between the total number of rows in the data frames in the split list and the variable used to split the original data frame.

If you know or can compute the changes required to make the variable used to split the original data frame then `unsplit()` can be deployed. Though it is more than likely that this will not be trivial.

The general solution is, as @Andrew Sannier mentions is the `do.call(rbind, ...)` idiom:

```
> spl <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
> str(do.call(rbind, spl))
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  22.8 24.4 22.8 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 27.3 26 30.4 ...
 $ cyl : num  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ disp: num  108 146.7 140.8 78.7 75.7 ...
 $ hp  : num  93 62 95 66 52 65 97 66 91 113 ...
 $ drat: num  3.85 3.69 3.92 4.08 4.93 4.22 3.7 4.08 4.43 3.77 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.32 3.19 3.15 2.2 1.61 ...
 $ qsec: num  18.6 20 22.9 19.5 18.5 ...
 $ vs  : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 4 4 4 3 4 5 5 ...
 $ carb: num  1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Outside of base R, also consider:

- `data.table::rbindlist()` with the side effect of the result being a `data.table`
- `dplyr::bind_rows()` which despite its somewhat confusing name will bind rows across lists

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Andrew Sannier works but has the side-effect that the rownames get changed. `rbind` adds the list names to them, so e.g. "Datsun 710" becomes "4.Datsun 710". One can use `unname` in between to avoid this problem.

Complete example:

```
mtcars_reorder = mtcars[order(mtcars$cyl), ] #reorder based on cyl first
l1 = split(mtcars_reorder, mtcars_reorder$cyl) #split by cyl
l1 = unname(l1) #remove list names
l2 = do.call(what = "rbind", l1) #unsplit
all(l2 == mtcars_reorder) #check if matches
#> TRUE
```